# mysql: ERROR 1040 (HY000): Too many connections and can't restart because of Error: 28 (No space left on device)

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, disk-space, max-connections

My app crashes because there are too many connections open and mysql does not make me log in as root showing the same problem.
After restarting mysql, it does not restart because of no space on disk

Comment: Show us your configuration (my.cnf).  Possibly some things were set too high.  How much RAM do you have?  How much disk?  How big is the dataset?

Comment: Is the ibtmp file table taking all space ?

Comment: @RickJames hello ricky, thank you for your comment. The machine has 2GB RAM and 50GB of SSD. At that moment 40 GB of ssd were taken by BIN files. With the retention policy updated (5 days max), these files take max 8 GB.

Comment: I will provide my cnf file this afternoon @RickJames

Comment: @JYOTIRAJAI how can I check ibtmp? what did you meant with ibtmp?

Comment: Are you referring to "binlog" files?  8GB per day is a huge amount; what queries are causing so much?  Do you have replication?

Comment: @DomenicoScalera in some cases that cause for "no space left" can be queries running on instance are heavy/bulky & using temporary table which may cause usage of disk temporary table which are created in ibtmp file &  this tablespace file size is expanding & reclaim is not possible without restart of an instance. So, was asking to check size of this tablespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here there is a full guide on how I solved the issue:

I tried to log in as root with the command:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

But it did not work for me, mysql kept giving the error:

```
ERROR 1040 (HY000): Too many connections
```

After some searches I tried

```
service mysqld restart --max-connections=500
```

This way stopped mysqld, which wasn't able to restart because at the same time my disk was full and receiving:

```
 Error: 28 (No space left on device)
```

Then, in order to inspect on ubuntu where my space was occupied I used the command:

```
du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -hr
```

That let me know all the space was occupied by binlog files of mysql.
I couldn't remove files by hand, it is not recommended procedure.
But I did not have anything to remove and I was not able to start mysql to purge the binlog files.
Then I run the following command which gave me enough space to restart mysql:

```
apt-get clean
service mysql restart || systemctl restart mysqld
```

At this point I was able to login to mysql and purge the binlog files with:

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2021-03-03 22:46:26';
```

But this is not a long term solution.
To avoid the problem in the future I did:

```
SET GLOBAL binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 432000; // 5 days of binlog files
```

I am going to improve this answer when I solve the maximum connection issue for a long term solution.