# How to add a volume to current in use MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-8.0, disk-space

related to the problem I faced here [No space left on device](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/287450/mysql-error-1040-hy000-too-many-connections-and-cant-restart-because-of-err), I want to adopt a long term solution about the point no space left on device. One of the action includes to add a volume to the machine in which the database runs (MySQL 8, Ubuntu 20.04 and Digital Ocean provider).

I would like to know which one is safest way and rules to follow in order to avoid loosing reference and/or data when I will add a volume on the machine.
Considering that this database is running in production without any replication.

Thank you in advance for the support

Comment: Start by asking the cloud provided to give you a bigger machine.  Then we can discuss shrinking your data and _maybe_ downsizing again.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this guide, very useful and complete

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04